# Count polygons crossed by other polygons using ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, polygon, arcgis-10.3, count, boundaries

I have two polygon feature classes, census blocks and voting precincts. 
What I want to get is the count of census blocks that contain more than one voting precinct, that is, where precinct boundaries split a block.

Comment: There's a number of ways to address this, some manual and some scripted.  Unioning the two FCs, then doing summary statistics on block count by precinct is probably easiest.

Comment: If your problem is more general, with, for example historic overlapping precincts you could use [REGIONPOLYCOUNT](http://www.fs.fed.us/digitalvisions/tools/download/regionpolycount.htm), but only if you have access to workstation ARC/INFO. For some strange reason Esri didn't port that to later versions (?)

Comment: @Vince, I'm not familiar with summary statistics. What exactly are the parameters in the tool I'm looking for? Or do you mean Summarize in the attribute table?

Comment: If you're not familiar with a Desktop capability, you can pull up the [documentation](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/) and use the Search box with the term.  A search on "summary statistics" returned [this](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/analysis-toolbox/summary-statistics.htm)

Comment: After some trial and error on the fields, got the count using @Vince recommendation. If you want to post as an answer, I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented by @Vince:

> There's a number of ways to address this, some manual and some
>   scripted. [Union](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/analysis-toolbox/union.htm)ing the two FCs, then doing [summary statistics](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/analysis-toolbox/summary-statistics.htm) on
>   block count by precinct is probably easiest.